# this.state.checkboxes.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, jsx

```
state = {
    checkboxes: this.props.dataOpt.map(item=>
    ({
      id: item.value,
      title: item.label,
      checked: true
    })
  )}

_renderItems = (item, containerStyle, titleStyle) => (
    <CommonCheckBox
      title={item.label}
      textStyle={titleStyle}
      containerStyle={containerStyle}
      key={item.value}
      onPress={this.toggleCheckbox(item.value)}
    />
  )

handleCheckBoxStatus(id){
    const selectedCheckbox = this.state.checkboxes.find((checkbox) => checkbox.id === id)
    return selectedCheckbox.checked
  }
```

error:
this.state.checkboxes.find is not a function.
Does anyone know why it show this error? I'm pretty sure this.state.checkboxes is an array.

Comment: What browser and what version of said browser?  https://caniuse.com/#search=find

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure it's an array"*  ...  `console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.checkboxes))` is better than assuming

Comment: Sure but could be getting modified elsewhere

Comment: In your code, I cannot see any call to `handleCheckBoxStatus` function. can you please show us more code.  and one more thing on `CommonCheckBox` you are passing a callback to `onPress` that should be `onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(item.value)}` like this.